# SDL Window fullscreen on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, sdl, fullscreen

i have this code that use SDL

```
void ToggleFullscreen(){
    fullscreen=!fullscreen;
    if(fullscreen){ //if is windowed
        SDL_SetWindowFullscreen(window,SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP); //set fullscreen
        SDL_GetWindowSize(window,&WIDTH,&HEIGHT); //get fullscreen size
    }
    else{ //if is already fullscreen
        SDL_SetWindowFullscreen(window,0); //set windowed 
        HEIGHT=WINDOWED_HEIGHT; //set windowed height
        WIDTH=WINDOWED_WIDTH; //set windowed width
        SDL_SetWindowSize(window,WIDTH,HEIGHT); //update window size
    }
    Commands_Rect.x=WIDTH-Commands_Rect.w; //update commands_rect width to ensure correct placement
    SDL_SetWindowPosition(window,SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED); //move window to the middle of the screen
    buildArr(); //regenerate the vector because the width of the window is changed
    GetMenu(); //regenerate menu because the width of the window is changed
    ShowMenu(); //show the menu
}
```

that basically set Full-screen on or off. on windows it works perfectly fine, however on Ubuntu, if I set Full-screen on, the content of the window is missing or bugged(it works perfectly fine if not full screen).

if the window is full screen I can still for example made it windowed so maybe it's a rendering problem. I don't know how to fix this because on windows it works without any problem.
can someone help me?
thanks

example that works on windows and not on linux

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool menuShowed=false; //true if the menu is currently on screen, false if not
bool run=true; //variable for the main loop
bool fullscreen=false; //variable to check if fullscreen is on or off
SDL_Window *window=NULL; //main window
SDL_Renderer *renderer=NULL; //main renderer
TTF_Font *arial=NULL; //text font
SDL_Surface *surfaceMenu=NULL; //surface that contains the menu
SDL_Texture *textureMenu=NULL; //texture that contains the menu
SDL_Rect Menu_Rect; //rectangle where textureMenu will be rendered
SDL_Event event; //variable for event poll
SDL_Color White={255,255,255}; //text color

int WIDTH=1280,HEIGHT=720; //current size of the window
const int WINDOWED_WIDTH=1280,WINDOWED_HEIGHT=720;

void GetMenu(){
const char text[]="Sample";
    surfaceMenu=TTF_RenderText_Blended_Wrapped(arial,text,White,WIDTH);
    textureMenu=SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer,surfaceMenu);
    Menu_Rect.x=0;
    Menu_Rect.y=0;
    Menu_Rect.w=surfaceMenu->w;
    Menu_Rect.h=surfaceMenu->h;
    SDL_FreeSurface(surfaceMenu);
    surfaceMenu=NULL;
}
void ShowMenu(){
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,38,38,168,0);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer,textureMenu,NULL,&Menu_Rect); 
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    menuShowed=true;
}
void init(){ //function that initialize everything needed
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    TTF_Init();
    SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY,"1");
    window=SDL_CreateWindow("Sorting Visualizer by Fxby16",SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,WIDTH,HEIGHT,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN); //initializing the window
    renderer=SDL_CreateRenderer(window,-1,SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED); //initializing the renderer (hardware acceleration enabled)
    arial=TTF_OpenFont("fonts/arial.ttf",24);
    GetMenu();
}

void close(){
    SDL_DestroyTexture(textureMenu);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
}
void ToggleFullscreen(){
    fullscreen=!fullscreen;
    if(fullscreen){ //if is windowed
        SDL_SetWindowFullscreen(window,SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP); //set fullscreen
        SDL_GetWindowSize(window,&WIDTH,&HEIGHT); //get fullscreen size
    }
    else{ //if is already fullscreen
        SDL_SetWindowFullscreen(window,0); //set windowed 
        HEIGHT=WINDOWED_HEIGHT; //set windowed height
        WIDTH=WINDOWED_WIDTH; //set windowed width
        SDL_SetWindowSize(window,WIDTH,HEIGHT); //update window size
    }
    SDL_SetWindowPosition(window,SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED); //move window to the middle of the screen
    GetMenu(); //regenerate menu because the width of the window is changed
    ShowMenu(); //show the menu
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    init();
    ShowMenu();
    while(run){
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
            switch(event.type){
                case SDL_QUIT: //close button pressed
                    run=false;
                    break;
                case SDL_KEYDOWN: //any key pressed
                    SDL_Keycode key=event.key.keysym.sym;
                    if(key==SDLK_q){ //q to quit (same as pressing close button)
                        run=false;
                    }
                    if(key==SDLK_f){ //f to toggle fullscreen
                        ToggleFullscreen();
                    }
                    if(key==SDLK_m){ //m to show the menu
                        ShowMenu();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    close(); //destroying textures,renderer,window and quitting sdl

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: What's up with `SDL_GetWindowSize` and then setting the window size to that number? Just do `SDL_SetWindowFullscreen(..., SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP)` and don't touch the window after that. Wait for a resize event to arrive if you need to know the new size.

Comment: I used set window size because when turning off fullscreen the window was not being resized correctly, maybe I should move this line into the else since when turning on fullscreen it's useless

Comment: Hmm, weird. I would expect it to do the right thing without it.

Comment: I tried it again now. without set window size it doesn't resize correctly. back to the fullscreen issue, by testing it again I saw that when enabling fullscreen the window is moved to the top left corner of the screen with all the content missing without being resized, and the other part of the screen is just black

Comment: Is this an OpenGL window? Does your code utilize the new window size correctly? So many questions and no [mcve]. Can you make a small program from scratch that draws something and demonstrates the bug, so we can test it ourselves?

Comment: example added. i pasted the most important parts from my main project and removed the unnecessary. i hope i have not made any big mistake while copying. the problem in this code happens when pressing f to set fullscreen on ubuntu

Comment: *"hope i have not made any big mistake"* Did you test that the new program reproduces the issue?

Comment: yes, i tested on windows, where there isn't the problem, and on linux where there is the problem

Comment: You need to be constantly redrawing the screen. (Or only on specific events, but that's more tricky. I think that's `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED`?) I'm able to reproduce, but when I press `M` after `F`, the window starts showing correctly.

Comment: it's strange, because pressing M it's calling ShowMenu() again, that was already called at the end of ToggleFullScreen(). the thing I can't figure out is that on windows this problem isnt present. I will try to look again at the code tomorrow to see if I can find something. Thanks for now, really appreciate your help

Comment: You're welcome. Thing is, this just isn't how you normally draw things on screen. Most apps do one of two things: either redraw constantly (games, etc), or use `SDL_WaitEvent` to redraw only on events (and even then, filter what events you want to redraw on). If you stick to that, you shouldn't have any issues.

Answer (score -1):

I think i found a fix. The fact that pressing `M` after setting fullscreen was showing the menu correctly, made me think that the actual resizing of the window or something else takes longer on Ubuntu than it does on Windows. so i tried adding a 5ms delay before showing the menu and that seems to have fixed the problem. Here the code with the small change:

```
void ToggleFullscreen(){
    fullscreen=!fullscreen;
    if(fullscreen){
        SDL_SetWindowFullscreen(window,SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP);
        SDL_GetWindowSize(window,&WIDTH,&HEIGHT);
    }
    else{ 
        SDL_SetWindowFullscreen(window,0);
        HEIGHT=WINDOWED_HEIGHT;
        WIDTH=WINDOWED_WIDTH;
        SDL_SetWindowSize(window,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    }
    Commands_Rect.x=WIDTH-Commands_Rect.w;
    SDL_SetWindowPosition(window,SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED); 
    buildArr(); 
    GetMenu();
    SDL_Delay(5); // <--- fix here
    ShowMenu();
}
```

probably the time needed depends on your machine, so maybe you have to increase the delay.
Thanks again to [@HolyBlackCat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2752075/holyblackcat) for the help

Comment: I'd rather redraw on `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED`. Having to insert arbitrary delays is a sign that you're misusing the API.

Comment: thanks, this seems to have fixed the problem and is surely better. before showing the menu i just loop until there is a `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED`